# Different kinds of subtotals in Pivot Tables (Excel)

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I would appreciate your support tackling an issue with subtotals in a pivot table...

I have a field which sums values from a table, but I would appreciate to have as subtotal the average values of a certain group.

Let me clarify what I mean:

The table looks like this:

```
PROGRAM              PROJECT                VALUE
P1                   Project 1.1            8
P1                   Project 1.2            1,94
P1                   Project 1.3            10,10
P1                   Project 1.4            5
```

As a result, I expect the pivot table to show me P1 = 6,26.
I set the Program field as AVERAGE however, take a look what is happening to my pivot table:

[image: Issue]

Any idea?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Your picture of the pivot table doesn't make sense to me.  It seems like it should also show a "Project" header.  To show just the average for Program, remove Project from the Row field.  I think I'm not understanding what you want.

Comment: Hello Doug, thanks for your comment. I want to get the average of the project results for a respective program. In the P1 case, I expect (8 + 1,94 + 10,10 + 5) / 6 = 6,26. What is currently happening is that the pivot table sums it up. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are many average options connected with PivotTables and I can only surmise you chose an unsuitable one or your Excel version is not the same as mine (if only for default settings) because when I pivot your sample data (having adjusted `,` to `.`s and abbreviated "Project" to "P") I see:

[image: SO12756974 example]

with my default (fairly standard) settings *after* I right-clicked on the cell showing `6.26` in the image (ie the result you require - before doing so Σ Values had defaulted to Sum of VALUE and this cell displayed 25.04) and in Value Field Settings... selected 'Average' for **Summarize value field by**.